# Varchar or medium text?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out the difference between varchar and medium text, im not sure which one to use with my gallery field in my database.

My gallery field will hold an array, which has an unknown length, so I'm thinking I should use medium text?

Comment: Please provide some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

`MEDIUMTEXT` can stores `16,777,215 bytes ~ 16MC`

With `VARCHAR` you can specify the length by your own, but maximum value is `65,535 bytes`

Comment: Thanks, so which would be best for my situation? I don;t know the length of what is going to be stored.

Comment: Panthro . . . Unless you are storing documents, `varchar()` should be fine.

Comment: With `VARCHAR`, you define the **maximum** length (in characters). Be aware that a UTF8 column will store 3 bytes per character.

Comment: What happens if I dont define the mx length (becuase I dont know what it should be)?